# flutter_staggered_grid_view infinite scroll from api feed

Tags: api, flutter, lazy-loading

I am using the **flutter_staggered_grid_view** package (https://github.com/letsar/flutter_staggered_grid_view) to have a feed of images. I want to implement something where first of all I can fetch say 30 images on initial screen load then when I reach the end and the scroll listener fires fetch more from the api. How do I change the below to do this? Can anyone give me any direction on docs etc. I think fundamentally this package is using gridview underneath but I am new to flutter so I'm unsure.

I just want an infinite scroll feed of images from an api.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent ==
          scrollController.offset) {
        // Get more
        print('End of screen');
      }
    });
  }

  List<String> imageList = [
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/15/16/25/clock-5834193__340.jpg',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/18/19/31/laptop-5582775_960_720.jpg',
    'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/woman-kayaking-in-fjord-in-norway-picture-id1059380230?b=1&k=6&m=1059380230&s=170667a&w=0&h=kA_A_XrhZJjw2bo5jIJ7089-VktFK0h0I4OWDqaac0c=',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/11/05/00/53/cellular-4602489_960_720.jpg',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/12/10/29/christmas-2059698_960_720.jpg',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/01/29/17/09/snowboard-4803050_960_720.jpg',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/06/20/01/university-library-4825366_960_720.jpg',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/11/22/17/28/cat-5767334_960_720.jpg',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/13/16/22/snow-5828736_960_720.jpg',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/15/16/25/clock-5834193__340.jpg',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/18/19/31/laptop-5582775_960_720.jpg',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// If you set your home screen as first screen make sure call [SizeConfig().init(context)]
    SizeConfig().init(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Platform.isIOS
          ? Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12, top: 5),
              child: CustomScrollView(
                controller: scrollController,
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
                    parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
                slivers: <Widget>[
                  SliverAppBar(
                    floating: true,
                    title: SvgPicture.asset(
                      "assets/images/logo-dark.svg",
                      height: getProportionateScreenWidth(40),
                    ),
                    actions: [
                      // Filter Button
                      FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => FilterScreen(),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "Filter",
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  CupertinoSliverRefreshControl(
                    onRefresh: () async {
                      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
                    },
                  ),
                  SliverStaggeredGrid.countBuilder(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 12,
                    itemCount: imageList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(15),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                          child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                            placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                            image: imageList[index],
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    staggeredTileBuilder: (index) {
                      return StaggeredTile.count(1, index.isEven ? 1.2 : 1.8);
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          : RefreshIndicator(
              color: kMainColor,
              displacement: 120,
              onRefresh: () async {
                await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
              },
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12, top: 5),
                child: CustomScrollView(
                  controller: scrollController,
                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
                    parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  ),
                  slivers: <Widget>[
                    SliverAppBar(
                      floating: true,
                      title: SvgPicture.asset(
                        "assets/images/logo-dark.svg",
                        height: getProportionateScreenWidth(40),
                      ),
                      actions: [
                        // Filter Button
                        FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => FilterScreen(),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            "Filter",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SliverStaggeredGrid.countBuilder(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 12,
                      itemCount: imageList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(15),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(15),
                            ),
                            child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                              placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                              image: imageList[index],
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      staggeredTileBuilder: (index) {
                        return StaggeredTile.count(1, index.isEven ? 1.2 : 1.8);
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When user is in the end you want to load more images yes?

Comment: Exactly ye, just append to whatever list is created on screen load from the api @Mr.ZeroOne

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the ScrollController for the scrolling detection at the bottom for the ListView and GridView. As you need the GridView i have created the ScrollController listner and added to the GridView's contollerfor the detection of the scroll. I have created the demo of it , please check it once. At first time it load the 10 items and when list comes to the bottom then it add more 10 items in it.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return HomeState();
  }
}

class HomeState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List dataList = new List<int>();
  bool isLoading = false;
  int pageCount = 1;
  ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    ////LOADING FIRST  DATA
    addItemIntoLisT(1);

    _scrollController = new ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 5.0)
      ..addListener(_scrollListener);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Gridview',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.red,
          accentColor: Color(0xFFFEF9EB),
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(),
            body: GridView.count(
              controller: _scrollController,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,

              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              children: dataList.map((value) {
                return Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                      ),
                      child: Text("Item ${value}"),
                    );


              }).toList(),
            )));
  }

  //// ADDING THE SCROLL LISTINER
  _scrollListener() {
    if (_scrollController.offset >=
            _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        print("comes to bottom $isLoading");
        isLoading = true;

        if (isLoading) {
          print("RUNNING LOAD MORE");

          pageCount = pageCount + 1;

          addItemIntoLisT(pageCount);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  ////ADDING DATA INTO ARRAYLIST
  void addItemIntoLisT(var pageCount) {
    for (int i = (pageCount * 10) - 10; i < pageCount * 10; i++) {
      dataList.add(i);
      isLoading = false;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hcDc.gif

Comment: Thank you, I'm just confused where dataList is coming from? I want a list of Images with id/name etc so I can navigate to another screen when someone clicks on an image. Will this be a future to make an api request?