# How to launch messages app and set the "To" field (the destination) with default email address programmatically in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, flutter-dependencies

When the user taps on "contact us" button, I want to launch messages app in both Android and iOS and then set the destination with an already known email address in flutter.
How can I do this? Impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) for opening url's which in your case would be the following:

```
final url = 'mailto:$mailAddress';
if (await canLaunch(url)) {    
  launch(url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Amir. Are you sure this will work in both android and iOS?

Comment: @Johnson This `mailto:` a pretty standard protocol, it would probably also work on macOS and Windows and Linux too

Comment: Thanks. Have a great day.